# how many times is repeated cell value in a column . Using Find method

Tags: vba, excel, find

The program should receive, how many times is repeated cell value (D34) in a column (D34:D99) . But the program displays zero.

```
Sub распознать()
Dim r As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
Dim iLoop As Long
Dim book1 As Workbook
Dim Team As String 
Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 4\БАЗА ДАННЫХ\болванка\сезон для проги\Англия\1-ое место\3.xlsx")
 Team = book1.Worksheets("3").Range("D34")
With book1.Worksheets("3").Range("D33:D99")

    Set r = .Find(What:="Team")
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = r.Address
        Do
            iLoop = iLoop + 1
            Set r = .FindNext(r)
        Loop While Not r Is Nothing And r.Address <> firstAddress And iLoop < 20
    End If
End With
book1.Worksheets("3").Range("D100").Value = iLoop
book1.Save
```

End Sub

Comment: I'm unclear on why the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) is not sufficient but you should expand the parameters of the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) beyond the defaults left by the previous usage.

Comment: I find another solution. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear on why the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) is not sufficient but you should expand the parameters of the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) beyond the defaults left by the previous usage and use `.Find(What:=Team)` with no quotes.

If you are looking for the cell value of `Range("D34")` within `Range("D33:D99")`, it will always be found at least once.

Comment: posting mine while you already posted yours. hope you don't mind . while on the OP's side _"repetita juvant"_ always holds true!

Answer (score 1):

change

```
Set r = .Find(What:="Team")
```

to

```
Set r = .Find(What:=Team)
```

and also follow Jeeped suggestions